# iOS Adjust size UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i tried few things, and i don't arrive to adjust the webview at its content..

I called my webview "_contenuNews", and i send my text in the webview :

```
    [_contenuNews loadHTMLString:[test_news contenu] baseURL:URLImg];
```

I tried to update the size with :

```
    [_contenuNews sizeToFit], but it's not working...
```

I tried to use the function webViewdidFinishLoad, but i never go in this function, i don't know why...

Help please ?

thx,

EDIT 1 :

I have that in the viewDidLoad of my tableviewcontroller :

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];

     URLImg = [NSURL URLWithString:@"XXXXX.fr/images/"];

    _titleNews.text = [test_news titre]; 

    _introNews.text = [test_news intro]; 

    [_introNews sizeToFit]; 

    [_contenuNews loadHTMLString:[test_news contenu] baseURL:URLImg]; 
}
```

And i tried that :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { 
    [_contenuNews sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero]; 
    [_contenuNews sizeToFit]; 
    //[_contenuNews setScalesPageToFit:YES]; 
}
```

(i tried with only "[_contenuNews setScalesPageToFit:YES];" in this function but it's not running)

Comment: If you never make it into `webViewDidFinishLoad:` this says to me that you aren't setting the delegate. Are you setting the delegate for your `UIWebView`? Do you have `UIWebViewDelegate` set in your header file (`.h`)? Please share your code of how you create and initialize the `UIWebView`. Also when do you call `sizeToFit`? Do you call it after your webview has loaded or before?

Comment: Hello, yes, i set the delegate on the storyboard. In my header file, i have this for the webview : @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *contenuNews;

Comment: My WebView was created on the storyboard, on my view. I didn't create it by the code.

Comment: At the top of your header do you have `@interface MyClassName : MySuperClass <UIWebViewDelegate>`? The `UIWebViewDelegate` is very important setting the delegate without having this in your header is absolutely pointless. So you will not be setting the delegate at all if this isn't in there.

Comment: oh my god :D yes, my bad, i forgot to add it in my interface, so now i can use this function, but now, i don't know what to set in :D

Comment: Try calling `[_contenuNews setScalesPageToFit:YES];`

Comment: Please share the code you do have for loading the webview.

Comment: I really have just that in the viewDidLoad of my TableViewController (for the webview of course, i have other things, but nothing about the webview) :  [_contenuNews loadHTMLString:[test_news contenu] baseURL:URLImg];

Comment: Please share everything as is in your code, there must be more then those two lines. So Please share otherwise that's it there is nothing else I can do to help.

Comment: I have that in the viewDidLoad of my tableviewcontroller :


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    URLImg = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.XXXXX.fr/images/"];

    _titleNews.text = [test_news titre];

    _introNews.text = [test_news intro];
    [_introNews sizeToFit];

    [_contenuNews loadHTMLString:[test_news contenu] baseURL:URLImg];
}

Comment: test_news is a object which contains text.

Comment: And i tried that :

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_contenuNews sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    [_contenuNews sizeToFit];
    //[_contenuNews setScalesPageToFit:YES];
}

(i tried with only "[_contenuNews setScalesPageToFit:YES];" but it's not running)

Comment: Please edit your question with your code. Just doing it in the comments makes it a lot harder to read.

Comment: oh, i tried again to set scales page to fit, but on the storyboard this time and i show the text, but it's dezoom, the font size seems to be very little, but it's doesn't solve the poblem :/

Comment: The way it works is it will zoom out to fit your site into the webview if it isn't mobile optimized it's not going to do it for your. So now you need to edit your html css javascript to make your site mobile responsive.

Comment: It's strange because the site is responsive, i check recently on few phones, and it's perfect :/

Comment: i can't zoom with the webview ? I found before something to zoom, but i don't find it any more :(

Comment: Mhh, i thought about it, and we don't care if the site is responsive or not. Because i send in the WebView only the text that i caught.

"[_contenuNews loadHTMLString:[test_news contenu] baseURL:URLImg];"

test_news contenu contains just text with tag HTML.

Comment: Well it will always look funky then for best results with a `UIWebView` it's best off having a mobile optimized site.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, but in my case, i don't show directly my site, i just want to show text in this webview, not my site.

Comment: It's not much of an issue to implement some basic mobile optimization just check the viewport and use different css if mobile. Have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: I don't know, if i don't understand, or if you don't understand my problem ^^

My problem, is, that i want my WebView be automatically adjusted.

Comment: My website is responsive, but i don't want to show my site in the application, it's useless, i need to show only a text that i take from my website.

Comment: From your question it sounds like you want to adjust your site to fit in the viewport of the `UIWebView` not take certain content from that website that is being displayed in the webview. So you want to ignore all the website except for a specific piece of text in the site is that right? Nothing to do with adjusting to fit like your question makes out to be.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear.

I take a piece of text on my website, and i want to put it in the WebView, and i want that the WebView adjust his size according to the text.

Comment: But, this text comes from an API jSON. So i don't take the text directly on the website, i take it on a webservice.